# rbenv: Permission Denied

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I was following along with Ryan's RailsCast Episode 339.  I had installed rbenv and could run `ruby -v`.  I exited my session, and when I tried to come back in (via `su deployer` from `root`, I got this error

```
/home/deployer/.rbenv/bin/rbenv: line 20: cd: /root: Permission denied
```

Here is the `rbenv` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
[ -n "$RBENV_DEBUG" ] && set -x

resolve_link() {
  $(type -p greadlink readlink | head -1) "$1"
}

abs_dirname() {
  local cwd="$(pwd)"
  local path="$1"

  while [ -n "$path" ]; do
    cd "${path%/*}"
    local name="${path##*/}"
    path="$(resolve_link "$name" || true)"
  done

  pwd
  cd "$cwd"
}

if [ -z "${RBENV_ROOT}" ]; then
  RBENV_ROOT="${HOME}/.rbenv"
else
  RBENV_ROOT="${RBENV_ROOT%/}"
fi
export RBENV_ROOT

if [ -z "${RBENV_DIR}" ]; then
  RBENV_DIR="$(pwd)"
else
  cd "$RBENV_DIR" 2>/dev/null || {
    echo "rbenv: cannot change working directory to \`$RBENV_DIR'"
    exit 1
  } >&2
  RBENV_DIR="$(pwd)"
  cd "$OLDPWD"
fi
export RBENV_DIR


shopt -s nullglob

bin_path="$(abs_dirname "$0")"
for plugin_bin in "${RBENV_ROOT}/plugins/"*/bin; do
  bin_path="${bin_path}:${plugin_bin}"
done
export PATH="${bin_path}:${PATH}"

hook_path="${RBENV_HOOK_PATH}:${RBENV_ROOT}/rbenv.d:/usr/local/etc/rbenv.d:/etc/rbenv.d:/usr/lib/rbenv/hooks"
for plugin_hook in "${RBENV_ROOT}/plugins/"*/etc/rbenv.d; do
  hook_path="${hook_path}:${plugin_hook}"
done
export RBENV_HOOK_PATH="$hook_path"

shopt -u nullglob


command="$1"
case "$command" in
"" | "-h" | "--help" )
  echo -e "rbenv 0.3.0\n$(rbenv-help)" >&2
  ;;
* )
  command_path="$(command -v "rbenv-$command" || true)"
  if [ -z "$command_path" ]; then
    echo "rbenv: no such command \`$command'" >&2
    exit 1
  fi

  shift 1
  exec "$command_path" "$@"
  ;;
esac
```

Line 20 is `cd "$cwd"`

Any ideas on why I get this error when I try to come back into a session?

Comment: It appears that you're in /root when you switch user to "deployer".  Try making sure you're in a directory that "deployer" has access to.

Comment: You're right.  I was in `/root`, which I thought deployer would have access to since deployer is in the admin group.  You were right though, a simple switch of directories allowed me `su` correctly.  If you want to put this as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It appears that you're in /root when you switch user to "deployer". Try making sure you're in a directory that "deployer" has access to.

Credit goes to d11wtq

Answer (score 2):

Full steps:

```
cd
rm -rf ~/.rbenv
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-vars.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-vars
exec $SHELL

rbenv -v

rbenv install 3.0.1
rbenv versions
rbenv global 3.0.1

ruby -v
```