# rbenv Permission denied with Assetic on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, symfony, ubuntu, rbenv

I struggled for hours trying to have Assetic with Sass and Compass working on my production server.

The error is:

```
sh: 1: /root/.rbenv/shims/ruby: Permission denied
```

This is because my rbenv instalation is under the /root directory so Assetic doesn't have the permision to use it.

I've checked similar issues:

- "[Rbenv permission denied issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213078/rbenv-permission-denied-issue)"
- "[rbenv: Permission Denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951043/rbenv-permission-denied?rq=1)"
- "[Should rbenv be installed system-wide, or at a user level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815750/should-rbenv-be-installed-system-wide-or-at-a-user-level)"

but they didn't help.

I'm using Apache so I guess the default user is "www-data".

As explained in one of the above questions, I tried to grant www-data the permission in /root but either this didn't work or I did it wrong.

```
sudo chown -R www-data ~/.rbenv
```

This is the complete error:

```
[exception] 500 | Internal Server Error | Assetic\Exception\FilterException
    [message] An error occurred while running:
    '/root/.rbenv/shims/ruby' '/usr/local/bin/compass' 'compile' '/var/www/myapp/app/cache/dev' '--boring' '--images-dir' '/var/www/myapp/app/../web/uploads/img' '--config' '/var/www/myapp/app/cache/dev/assetic_compassu3IAzJ' '--sass-dir' '' '--css-dir' '' '/var/www/formation-hero/app/cache/dev/assetic_compassPbwM3H.scss'

    Error Output:
    sh: 1: /root/.rbenv/shims/ruby: Permission denied
```

I'm using Apache on Ubuntu 14.04

```
#  which ruby
/root/.rbenv/shims/ruby

# which compass
/usr/local/bin/compass

# which rbenv
/root/.rbenv/bin/rbenv

# rbenv -v
rbenv 1.0.0-14-gc388331
```

Symfony 2.7 is installed under /var/www/myapp/

What should I do to either give right to Apache to use the /root repository or, maybe better, how do I install rbenv for my Symfony2 project?

Everything is working fine on my localhost with OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have experience with the said components but assuming that the user who is executing the file is www-data it might be an issue with the permissions of the /root/.rbend/shims/ruby file.

Run the command `sudo chmod o+x /root/.rbenv/shims/ruby` wich will give execute permissions to the owner of the file, presumably www-data since you ran the chown command.

If it still doesn't work run the command `ls -l /root/.rbenv/shims/ruby`, the 4th character of the first column should be `x`, indicating the owner has execution permissions.

For more info on linux file permissions check "[Understanding and Using File Permissions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions)".

Comment: Thank you Miguel Alexandre. I changed the permision to 777 and it works.
Here he the command is anyone is looking for it. chmod 777 /root/.rbenv/shims/ruby